# AJAX call to Spring MVC works, but doesn't hit success function

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm doing what seems to be an extremely simple ajax call to my Spring controller.  It hits the controller fine, and that println gets printed, but I never get inside the AJAX success function.  Any ideas?

My AJAX call:

```
$.post(SERVER_LOC, function(){
  alert("success!");
});
```

My Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void home(String s) {
    System.out.println("In the controller!");
}
```

Comment: you are not returning anything..

Comment: @smk Yes, but response status should be 200, so success callback should be called, am I wrong? Try to add the `@ResponseBody` annotation as well.

Comment: Use debugger of chrome or firefox to see what is the actual response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.  This code is correct.  The problem was I was trying to make this request across domains from a different project.  Apparently I cannot receive a request back from the server cross-domain when I do this.  I moved everything to one project and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody //this will parse the returned Object to JSON
public String/*or some other type*/ home(String s) {
    System.out.println("In the controller!");
    return "something";
}
```